# MySQL change ROW1 if ROW2 contains "string"

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a list of items in a database. I have the columns `item_name` and `is_tradable`. I want to be able to go through the names in `item_name` and check if they contain a certain string, e.g. "Gold". If they contain that string, change `is_tradable` from 'yes' to 'no'.

e.g.: item_name "gold gloves" contains "gold", so is_tradable = "no"

I'm not sure how to check if a varchar contains a string.

My table shcema is something like this:

```
[Item_name, varchar(255), PrimaryKey]    
[is_tradable, varchar(255) ]    
[other random rows not needed here]
```

e.g.:

```
[item_name: gold_gloves, is_tradable: yes]
```

I want to be able to check if item_name contains "gold" so I can change `is_tradable`.

```
 [item_name: gold_gloves, is_tradable: no]
```

Comment: So some code stuff that you have tried? this is not A CODE MAKING PLATEFORM.

Comment: Can you please provide the table structure, some sample data and the result you're trying to get?

Comment: @Mureinik I have added some more info, what you asked for. That might make it easier.

Comment: @anantkumarsingh Calm down. I'm not asking for the code to be done for me, I was asking how to do a specific thing that I had no idea to. I have given a lot of data on my question. If you don't know how to help me and can't be constructive, please leave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `like` operator to check if the name contains `gold`:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET    is_tradable = 'no'
WHERE  item_name LIKE '%gold%'
```

Note that depending on the table's collation, `LIKE` may or may not be case sensitive. If you are unsure about the values in your table, you could just force all values to lower case:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET    is_tradable = 'no'
WHERE  LOWER(item_name) LIKE '%gold%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are familiar with the connection details and the rest, and assuming that the table name is `items`, you could do:

Using PDO:

```
// Assuming $db contains the connection
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE items SET is_tradable='no' WHERE Item_name LIKE '%Gold%' OR Item_name LIKE %gold%");
$stmt->execute();
```

What the above statement does is that it searches for every row where the `Item_name` "contains" the string `Gold` or `gold` and sets the row's `is_tradable` column to 'no'.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate twice on you mysql results.

- First to flag the string you're looking for with a boolean.
- If boolean == TRUE, iterate a second time and make the modifications.